# My Looper Pedal is louder than my normal signal, what should I do?

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects

I have a gig in a few days and I wanted to do live looping overdubs, but I am having an issue with the volume of the pedal (Ditto Stereo Looper).

For instance, I am playing the song in my desired volume with the pedal off, but when I get to the looping section and I press the pedal, the volume cranks up quite a bit and I don´t know what to do about it...

The pedal itself has a volume knob but it only works after the loop is recorded and played back, in other words, when I am recording the loop the volume is louder and I can only adjust the volume when I play it back

I don´t know what to do...

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's boring, but it's necessary: read all the instructions! Occasionally, I re-read some of mine, and find out extra things a piece of equipment will do, even after several years of using it.

Comment: Have you tried using the volume control?

Answer (score 3):

I just had a quick look at the online manual. It says to hold down the backing track level switch while turning the level control.

[image]

https://www.manualsearcher.com/tc-electronic/ditto-stereo-looper/manual

I'm sure there will be more detail on the appropriate page.

Comment: If all else fails - read the instructions..?